# Why is my connection to Oracle failing after upgrading to Orbeon Forms 4.4

Tags: oracle, orbeon

I have a working instance of Orbeon Forms 4.3, which I setup to connect to Oracle. After upgrading to Orbeon Forms 4.4, connections to Oracle fail with different exceptions depending on the case, for instance:

- `org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsSubmissionException`
- `org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException`
- `org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.HttpStatusCodeException`

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

### Checking the source of the errors

Those exceptions are most likely only the symptom of the real cause. To be sure, change the your `log4j.xml` and `properties-local.xml` per the [development configuration](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-logging#TOC-Development-configuration), reproduce the problem, and check again your `orbeon.log`. Check if in the log you see now see an `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xdb/XMLType` exception.

### Solution

If you see that `NoClassDefFoundError`, you need to add the `xdb.jar` and `xmlparserv2.jar` to the directory where you currently have Oracle driver. Those two files are part of the Oracle driver, and come along the other "main jar", i.e. `ojdbc6_g.jar`. On Tomcat, you typically place those files in Tomcat's `lib` directory. Restart Tomcat, and your problem should be solved.

### Why this is happening

This is happening because Orbeon Forms 4.4 started sending XML "as XML" to Oracle, instead of "as CLOB". Because of this, the driver uses classes from `xdb.jar` and `xmlparserv2.jar`. In retrospect, this might not have been the best approach; it was done because it looked like the "right thing", but it isn't clear this has any performance or other benefit, and makes installation and upgrade harder, requiring additional jars.

### Update

This issue is [fixed in Orbeon Forms 4.5](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1484).